# get latest row for each user_id in BigQuery based on two conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Bigquery Table with 3 important columns:

`user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

Each `user_id` can have several records, for example:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| user_id  | created_at | updated_at  |    task_name    |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| user_1   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02  | some_task_name1 |
| user_1   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03  | some_task_name1 |
| user_1   | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-01  | some_task_name1 |
| user_2   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02  | some_task_name2 |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

For each `user_id` with the same `created_at` value, I want to select the record with the latest `updated_at`. So for example, in this example the output has to be:

```
    +----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
    | user_id  | created_at | updated_at  |    task_name    |
    +----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
    | user_1   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03  | some_task_name1 |
    | user_1   | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-01  | some_task_name1 |
    | user_2   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02  | some_task_name2 |
    +----------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I was trying this, but I don't know how to add the condition for the same `created_at`:

```
SELECT
  agg.table.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(table)
    ORDER BY
      updated_at DESC)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] agg
  FROM
    `dataset.my_table` table
  GROUP BY
    user_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select as value array_agg(t order by updated_at desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by user_id, created_at
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: excuse me, what means `t` in your query? I tried replaced it with the table name but i'am getting an error: table name "data" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.

Comment: `t` is just alias and represents the whole row that than being used in array_agg function  - leave it as is. just replace `data` with your real `table name` - i just updated answer to be clearer on this - let me know if this works for you now? it should :o)